# How to nest objects in DesignProperties.DataContext through XAML?

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have a WPF application, and in the main window's XAML, I have the following:

```
<d:DesignProperties.DataContext>
    <viewModels:MainWindowViewModel 
        IsProcessCanvasVisible="False"
        IsBrowseButtonVisible="True"
         />
    <!-- TODO Bind "Processes" for design time test -->
</d:DesignProperties.DataContext>
```

My TODO there points to the missing part. This viewModel has a property called Processes, which is a `List<Process>`.

I would like to instantiate some elements through XAML so I can work with the bindings in design time. I wanted to do this in XAML in order to keep the design-time bindings to its declarative nature. (Creating fake classes just for design time didn't look good to me.)

Can this be done? If so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you can easily create objects within xaml.

This should work:

```
<viewModels:MainWindowViewModel 
    IsProcessCanvasVisible="False"
    IsBrowseButtonVisible="True"
 >
  <viewModels:MainWindowViewModel.ProcessList>
      <Process ... />
  </viewModels:MainWindowViewModel.ProcessList>
```

But you might struggle about the List< Process > within xaml. So create a type inheriting from List< Process > and use this type in you viewmodel

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the answer. Would you mind to elaborate on the warning that you gave regarding `List<Process>`? Is that because of generics and XAML not getting along?

Comment: Yes exactly, the generics are making trouble in XAML